# Can we have an hdfs tag?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

I tried creating an hdfs tag an acronym for Hadoop Distributed File System, but it got blocked because there is an hdf tag ~ Hierarchical Data Format (HDF)

Can we have an hdfs tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just created the [hdfs](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hdfs) tag on https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/186813/what-are-the-opensource-tools-for-spatial-data-migration-to-the-hadoop-distribut

It seemed easy to do so I am thinking mod privileges must enable me to do something with tag creation that the normal [create tags privilege](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) does not.

I'm not certain that the current and expected question volume warrants an [hdfs](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hdfs) tag separate from the [hadoop](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hadoop) tag, but we can make it a synonym later if it proves unwarranted.